# Linq-to-SQL problem

Tags: linq-to-sql

Find all customers whose purchase is less than 10000

```
var Customer = from c in _NorthWindDataContext.Customers
               join o in _NorthWindDataContext.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID
               group c by c.CustomerID into CutGroup
               where CutGroup.Sum(tab => tab.Orders.Sum(t => t.Order_Details.Sum(t1 => t1.Quantity * t1.Quantity))) < 10000
               select new
               {
                  CustomerID = CutGroup.Key,
                  Total = CutGroup.Sum(tab => tab.Orders.Sum(t => t.Order_Details.Sum(t1 => t1.Quantity *  t1.Quantity))),
               };
```

I have solved it but if I want to access `Order` table information then how can I access...

For your information I am binding customer to grid....so I can not use for each

Comment: customer has many orders which order's information u want to access. Furthermore, How collection of anonymous objects is supposed to populate a grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you want, you can try this:

```
    var Customer = from c in _NorthWindDataContext.Customers
                join o in _NorthWindDataContext.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID
                group c by c.CustomerID into CutGroup
                where CutGroup.Sum(tab => tab.Orders.Sum(t => t.Order_Details.Sum(t1 => t1.Quantity * t1.Quantity))) < 10000
                select new
                {
                    CustomerID = CutGroup.Key,
                    Total = CutGroup.Sum(tab => tab.Orders.Sum(t => t.Order_Details.Sum(t1 => t1.Quantity * t1.Quantity))),

                    Orders = from os in _NorthWindDataContext.Orders where os.CustomerID == CutGroup.Key select os,
                };
```